# Converting .mp4 to .264 using FFmpeg

Tags: terminal, ffmpeg, conversion, video-conversion

I am completely new to FFmpeg and am trying to convert my test.mp4 to (it has to be specifically) a .h264 file.

I have tried the following in Terminal:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:v libx264 test.h264
```

but get the following back:

> command not found

I tried directing it to my desktop as followed:

```
~/Bureaublad/media$ ./ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:v libx264 test.h264
```

But then got back:

> No such file or directory

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `.h264` file. Do you perhaps want the raw H264 data stream? What’s the output of `ffprobe test.mp4`? It could already contain the desired data, you’d just have to demux it. // Also, what operating system are you using? You should install ffmpeg properly via its package manager, if possible.

Comment: I haven't heard of a .h264 either, but I'm looking at one atm, which is a video that can't be opened by OS but can be played via the Raspberry. Only this type can be played by the Raspberry (perhaps this is the Raw h264 data stream you are talking about?)
Operating system: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: On OS X/macOS, I recommend using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install ffmpeg. Also, what command are you using on the Pi to play the movie?

Comment: Oh my, I thought it would be so easy, haha! The thing is, I have no idea. I used it from someone who already arranged/programmed a video loop thing etc on the SD card. The only thing I had to do was to convert my video to .h624. The video on the USB atm is in this format and works obviously as it's playing right now. I shall have a look right now and see what I can find of the SD card.

Answer (score 10):

try this:
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -an -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 test.h264

source: https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-May/006647.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately I get the same error back! .. Have I perhaps forgotten something major?

Comment: which error are you getting? "no such file or directory" or "command not found"?

Comment: "Command not found"

Comment: are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am using MacOs

Comment: I never used MacOs, it seems you didn't install ffmpeg the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Your issues have nothing to do with converting video and everything to do with the location of the `ffmpeg` binary.

I assumed you downloaded `ffmpeg` from [evermeet.cx](http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/). That's fine, and I often provide that link to other macOS users to get a recent version.

Downloading the `.dmg` link may be easier than the `.7z`, because macOS can extract the `.dmg` without third-party tools.

Once extracted you can move the `ffmpeg` file into `/usr/local/bin` (it will ask for a password to do so). You can then just run the `ffmpeg` command from any directory.

Alternatively, you can move it wherever you want, but you'll have to provide the full path to the location, such as `~/Downloads/ffmpeg -i ...` or first navigate to the directory that it is in and then run `./ffmpeg -i ...` (note the `./` prefix).

Comment: Finder can't find such /usr/local/bin! I tried your alternative option ~/Downloads/ffmpeg -i ...

But rather did it like this: 
~/Bureaublad/ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:v libx264 test.h264

?

Comment: @Amy You're probably using Finder which is too dumbed down for this type of use (it probably hides non-typical directories). Use Terminal. If you must use Finder then press Command+Shift+G, then enter `/usr/local/bin`. Did the alternative location work for you? You showed your command but didn't say if it worked.

Comment: Ok, so! It seemed I didn't install ffmpeg properly, which I have done now. (through homebrew and terminal) which seems to work. I then tried to use ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:v libx264 test.h264 in terminal and it still didn't work. However this time it seems to run ffmpeg first and then give me the (no such file or directory!) error. So I'm one step further, haha. 
Does this mean I'm doing something wrong in terms of file names? (swapping them for example?)

Comment: O, and to answer your previous question: I haven't tried this yet, no. Should I do this anyway? (I don't know how in this case, for I installed ffmpeg through Homebrew and terminal and therefor have not got a file to extract :) )

Comment: @Amy You have to provide the correct path to the input file in your `ffmpeg` command. As is, your `ffmpeg` command would expect `test.mp4` to be in the current directory. As for the "alternative location", no, you don't need to do any of that since you apparently now already got `ffmpeg` installed via homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

To transform an MP4 file to its H.264 codec using FFmpeg, you can use the following command:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

This command uses the following syntax:

- `-i input.mp4`: Specifies the input file that you want to transform to H.264.
- `-c:v libx264`: Specifies the H.264 video codec that will be used for encoding.
- `-crf 23`: Specifies the quality of the video compression. A lower value means higher quality, but a larger output file. A value of 23 is a good choice for most cases.
- `-preset medium`: Specifies the encoding speed. The medium value is a good choice for most cases, as it provides a good balance between speed and quality.
- `-c:a aac`: Specifies the AAC audio codec that will be used for encoding.
- `-b:a 128k`: Specifies the audio bitrate in kilobits per second. A value of 128k is a good choice for most cases.
- `output.mp4`: Specifies the name and location of the output file.

Note that the transformation to H.264 may take some time, depending on the duration of the input file and the power of your computer. You may also want to adjust the values of `-crf` and `-preset` to get the best results for your specific case.